# How to hide the SIDEBAR on login page angular 2

Tags: angular, sidebar

I am currently working on Angular 2 and I am stuck on one thing. I want to hide my sidebar component on just my login page and after logging in, display it like normal. But I can't find my way on how to do it. I have looked around and found *ngIf="nav.visible" but it throws console error and it's not good for production mode. Besides, it is for navbar and I am talking about sidebar.
Any idea how to get it done?
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: how is the sidebar implemented? How is login handled? It's impossible to answer your question without knowing this.

Comment: sidebar shouldn't be there from the first place. the way you're building it, tomorrow you'll post a new question "how do I hide sidebar on my 404 page". you should have a layout component, that holds the layout and have its own `router-outlet`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the Stackblitz links for your possible scenarios,

Link 1 -> [Using *ngIf to “hide” the NavBar](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-login-hide-navbar-ngif)

Link 2 -> [Using different layouts and routing config](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-login-hide-navbar-layout)

Just check this out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [multi layout in your angular project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-layout-example-btxngw)